# window.location.href = "prefs:root=Settings" not work in iOS 10

Tags: settings, ios10

I want to open iPhone setting app in Safari.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = "prefs:root=General&path=ManagedConfigurationList"
</script>
```

It is working in iOS 9, but it is not working in iOS 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace "prefs" to "App-Prefs" for iOS 10